# how to run visual studio without plugin and all third party feature

Tags: c#, visual-studio

i have installed many third party plugin add-ins in my visual studio.

now i want to run a instance of visual studio without all plugin addons and third party feature

just like mozilla firefox

how i can run visual studio without all plugin or add-ons. are their any method exist like other application

Answer (score 105, accepted):

All versions of visual studio can be started with a [set of arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xee0c8y7%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Using [devenv.exe /SafeMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241278%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) allows you to run any version of visual studio (devenv.exe) in SafeMode that will disable 3rd party plugins.

You can either run [devenv.exe /SafeMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241278%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) using the command line or by creating a new shortcut. The devenv.exe executable is located in the `\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe` directory under the directory your visual studio is installed.

You may also want to look at [devenv.exe /ResetSkipPkgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241276%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) if you are having problems.

Comment: Side note: `/SafeMode` will disable TFS as well

Comment: VS2012 had just started showing up (maybe related to installing VS Code) with just the menus and Extensions and Updates menu was showing up all black. Did a /resetsettings without result, then ran with /SafeMode and did some extension updates and not it works OK. Guess there may be case where there is some corruption that /SafeMode can help. In that case try to do some update or install some (any) extension to see if it fixes the issue

Comment: If you want to run VS as Admin in Safe Mode (e.g. so IIS projects will load), open up a command prompt as admin and then run `devenv.exe /SafeMode` from there.

Comment: Side note: /SafeMode will disable TestExplorer as well

Comment: Side note 2: with /SafeMode switch, ”Team Explorer” will be disabled. Left only with ”Pending changes” and ”Settings” enabled

Answer (score 13):

You can run the Visual Studio in safe mode, using the [`/SafeMode` switch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241278(v=VS.100).aspx) from the command line:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" /SafeMode
```

This will prevent all third-party packages and add-ons from loading. If you find yourself needing to do this frequently, you can even create a new shortcut to Visual Studio and add this switch to the target path so that double-clicking that shortcut automatically opens Visual Studio in safe mode.

Comment: Note: you can use [the developer command prompt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/developer-command-prompt-for-vs) to launch VS with these commands. Just search for "Developer Command Prompt" in the start menu.
Then run `devenv /SafeMode`

Comment: @Paesano2000 has the right answer. No need to worry about paths, versions, etc.

Answer (score 5):

For VS 2017, open a command window (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) and run the following command:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\devenv /SafeMode
```

In 64-bit machine:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\devenv /SafeMode
```

*Change `Community` with the respective version.

Comment: This is only true for `Community` edition. Replace `Community` in the path with your version (`Professional` or `Enterprise`)

Answer (score 2):

A other way is to reset the settings of Visual Studio

D:\VisualStudio2013\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe **/resetsettings**

In other cases VisualStudio is installed on a different harddrive.

Comment: btw, this one seems to close VS after doing the reset

Comment: @GeorgeBirbilis VS is not closing on my system, I feel sorry for you If the fix does not help you

Comment: Doing /SafeMode and then installing any extension/update fixed it in my case. Maybe some extension cache corruption?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use  /SafeMode switch for devenv.exe.

More at:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241278%28VS.80%29.aspx