# Is Visual Studio 2010 really really slow for some? Even with SP1?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

This normally happens when saving a very small file in a C# project/solution. I have also applied the Service Pack 1 but nothing has improved. I have nothing else running. My system is Windows 7, 4 gb of ram, over 50 gb of drive space, and an Intel I3. 
Also, if drop down to the Visual C# Express, will it still integrate with my Expression Blend 4? 
Thanks

Comment: Attention answerers: please make sure that your answers propose **possible solutions** to the problem, rather than simply confirming or denying a similar experience. The latter type of answer is not useful to people.

Answer (score 3):

I've usually found that when it's been really slow, it's been due to a bad plugin/add-in. Try disabling any "extras" you've installed.

Comment: And the easiest way to do that is [starting Visual Studio with the `/SafeMode` switch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182471/how-to-run-visual-studio-without-plugin-and-all-third-party-feature).

Comment: the funny thing is I have no known plugins, only stock out of box ones from Microsoft. I am just glad I am not the only one with this problem.

Answer (score 2):

WPF XAML-Editor is sometimes really very slow and also slows down the whole VS 2010 environment. If I close the editor, all is OK. I have observed this on more than one machine (but always x64) and with multiple solutions. SP1 has changed nothing on this issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

Some antivirus programs may cause this, as they scan whenever a file is changed. You need to add your project folders to its ignore list. Several months ago, VS was driving me crazy, as even closing a tab was taking about 10 seconds. Was thinking about upgrading my PC, but later i find out that not VS but Norton Antivirus was causing slow down.

Comment: That helps much thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with roughly the same settings.  I'm on a 64 Win 7 machine and simple things like Shift+Del ing lines cause VS to pause.  If I just delete a line (i.e., 'Backspace') the pause isn't there.  Closing lots of open files or checking in large quantities of changes also cause major slowdowns....trying to figure out if I should go back to 32-bit as there didn't seem to be as many hiccups.

Comment: Interesting, I can't repro this. VS 2010 is smooth as butter on my 64-bit machine. I arguably even get better performance than my 32-bit machines, but I suspect that has more to do with all the extra RAM headroom available. Are you using Resharper or some other add-ins?

Comment: If it is running smoothly, can someone provide me the exact build versions of each component on their Visual Studio? I want to ensure it matches what I got.

Comment: I'm not running any add-ons is the thing that gets me.  I've got 8 gigs of RAM, so I know that isn't holding me back.

Comment: VS 2010, Version 10.0.30319.1 RTMRel

Answer (score 1):

I have the default vs 2010 with Sp1 and its works pretty smoothly on my machine Intel i3 2.4 Ghz 4 gb Ram. The only plugin I have got is the AnkhSVn one.