# Visual Studio 2012 Slow To Close

Tags: visual-studio-2012, network-drive

I am running VS 2012. Working on a project that is stored on a mapped network drive. Whenever I go to close the solution it takes several minutes (5-7) for Visual Studio to close. It does eventually close, but very painful waiting for it to finish.

Anyone have any suggestions on how to fix?

Comment: Just curious, why are you not running your source code locally? If it's to keep it safe and/or backed up, you can easily use a source control system like subversion to keep a copy on the server.

Comment: @AaronS. Not running code locally. My employer thinks that implementing source control is too time consuming and that no code should be stored locally. Therefore we have build folders on network drives that are backed up nightly. Tried numerous times to change this, losing the battle. Agree with you 1000%.

Comment: Where do you work? I'll make a note never to apply for a job ...

Comment: Such ridiculously long delays could only be caused by network timeouts.  Assuming that it isn't caused by a thousand employees all following the company rules at the same time.  Use a network sniffer kind of tool to see what is timing out.

Comment: I hate to tell you this, but if you can't develop locally, and you aren't allowed to run any tools to help you debug it, I think you're stuck. Other people have made jokes about looking for another job, but I personally would not be happy under a manager that didn't understand basic source control and makes you develop like this.

Comment: Your boss needs to [take the Joel test](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000043.html).

Comment: Yes he does, and then I would get fired...

Comment: What actually causes the delay? Saving unsaved files, closing the project or actually shutting down Visual Studio? Break the process up into smaller parts maybe.

Comment: That could be a VS addin causing that problem. Try `devenv.exe /safemode` first and see if it works any better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182471/how-to-run-visual-studio-without-plugin-and-all-third-party-feature

Comment: I tried running in Safe Mode. The project closed instantly!!!! We are on to something here. Now how do I track down the culprit?

Comment: Well, Add-Ins are not the issue. I go to Tools --> Add-In Manager and it is empty.

Answer (score 2):

Try Process Monitor by SysInternals: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645

You can set the filters in such a way that only the Visual Studio 2012 executable is monitored and you will see each and any action towards files, network or registry. This might give you the idea about what's going on behind the scenes.

Comment: My computer is locked down so tight, doubt I would be allowed to install that.

Comment: Maybe www.jobserve.com would be a nice site to check? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It's typical. Because Visual Studio have to copy your data from local disk to map network. Also it have to check security options. Execute your project on your local Disk.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Remove all the "UNUSED" MS Access or other data files in the App_Data folder - including any that are in sub folders. If you have old versions in App_Data or in any sub folders then Visual Studio will have to open all of them even if your website does not use them.  In my case it took 2 - 3 minutes to open the website and even longer to close.  I had 50 or so backups and test databases I kept in various folders just a archives. I just moved them to another folder in my website.  Wow - Visual Studio now opens in a few seconds.