# Is there any way to prevent visual studio from inserting datafld-bind attribute

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, knockout.js

I am using vs2012 but I had this issue in vs2010 as well. Whenever I attempt to add a `data-bind` attribute, intellisense inserts `datafld-bind`. Thus I have to go back and edit it every time. I am writing a SPA with knockoutjs and consequently have numerous `data-bind` attributes throughout.

Is there anyway to modify/disable this behavior while keeping the rest of intellisense intact?

I've included the knockout tag since anyone doing knockout development in vs is likely to have the same problem...

Comment: In the Code Snippets Manager ?

Comment: try changing the HTML mode to HTML5, that will prompt VS to enter data- only. Try it and let us know if that works.

Comment: Not sure exactly where to set that. I went to Tools|Options|Text Editor|HTML and set target when no doctype to: XHTML5 to see what happens...I'll let you know. BTW, it was already at HTML5 and I have `<!DOCTYPE html>` in my .aspx file.

Comment: This is still an issue though it comes and goes. I've been unable to prevent it reliably :-(

Comment: I can't reproduce this in VS2010 or VS2013. You may have a VS extension that does it? Can you run VS in SafeMode and see if it stil happens: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182471/how-to-run-visual-studio-without-plugin-and-all-third-party-feature

Comment: I also can't reproduce this (VS2012)

Comment: I don't have VS installed anymore so I can't check (using webstorm these days). However, back in the day this issue was intermittent. I had no extensions or plugins except resharper. I often changed the default editor because VS would make the files read only during debugging.

Comment: You guys saying you can't reproduce this prompted me to try it with a plain old html file, as opposed to PHP (utilizing the VS.PHP plugin).  Lo and behold, this doesn't seem to be an issue within a plain html file.  So _maybe_ it has something to do with VS.PHP plugin, at least that gives me a path to go in.

Comment: Using VS2013 and never had this issue.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can [disable Intellisense for knockout](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/03/04/disabling-knockout-intellisense.aspx) altogether, but I don't believe you can modify the suggestions it returns.