# Visual studio 2013 crashing upon creating new table

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sql-server-express

Visual studio 2013 is crashing upon creating new table. Here's a step-by-step error replay:

- Create new Project (Windows Forms Application)
- Adding a button and a label
- Running app to check everything works on the application side
- PROJECT => Add New Item => Service-based Database
- DB added to Solution explorer
- Right-click on DB => Open (Server explorer open on left pane)
- Right-click on Tables => Add New Table
- Aaaand crash - Visual closes itself.
- When I reopen it, DB is still there, but empty (no tables).

(Apparently, need 10 rep to post images directly, so I'll post them through Imgur).
Here's a screenshot with details of the error on Windows Event Viewer (in Portuguese):

General Info: https://i.stack.imgur.com/plh6X.png
Datailed Info: https://i.stack.imgur.com/riPHb.png

It complains about this "`devenv.exe`" app.

Need some ideas to deal with this without reinstalling the whole Visual Studio.

SOLVED: Thanks to all guys. The repair through Programs and Features did the job.

Comment: Try some of these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182471/how-to-run-visual-studio-without-plugin-and-all-third-party-feature

Comment: Trying to repair VS through Programs and Features now. If it fails to correct my problem I'll try to run it without plugins, although I suspect it's not the problem, as I've never installed any 3rd party plugins.

Comment: What OS?  Do you have VS updates installed?

Comment: Windows 7 Ultimate x64 | Visual Studio Community 2013 with Update 4

Comment: create a crash dump (procdump or WER: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787181%28VS.85%29.aspx), oepn it in Windbg, setup symbols (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311503/en-us) and run **!analyze -v**. Uplaod the output to pastebin and post a link here.

Comment: Do not update the question like this. If you've solved the problem, create a new Answer with the corresponding info about the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer taken from OP's edit to original question:

SOLVED: The repair through Programs and Features did the job.