# Visual studio 2015 Javascript is white?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I just got visual studio 2015 and it's been working great, I did get a message there were and update for typescript so I downloaded and updated it.

Now all my javascript in visual studio have no color, everything is white.
The other languages such as c# / html etc works great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to reset the settings
Tools > Import and Export Settings > Reset all settings

Answer (score 0):

You can change the colours of the text/code in the various types of editor by going to the Tools/Options... menu, then go to Environment > Fonts and Colors.

More details on MSDN here (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh923906.aspx)

Comment: That does change the color of everything, I still want my varibles to me blue etc, now they are white.

Comment: That doesn't sound like something a genuine Typescript update would have done.  I would probably rule out any problematic add-ins etc. by starting VS in safe mode and see if it solves the problem.  If it does, check any other add-ins you've installed and eliminate them one at a time by disabling them and restarting VS.  See here (http://stackoverflow.com/a/4182492/939080) for details of safe mode.

Comment: It works in safemode, but I do not have any extension I can uninstall except resharper; did remove that and it's still white..

Comment: Safe mode only disables the add-ins and extensions.  If it works fine in safe mode, it can only be one of those.  Without seeing your PC in front of me, I'm afraid I can't do much more than suggest you investigate any add-ins and extensions that may be installed, disable all of them, and re-enable them one-at-a-time until your JS editor starts playing up again.  The last one you re-enable before that happens is likely to be the cause.  It's unlikely that you only have the ReSharper add-in installed.  If nothing else, things like the NuGet package manager interface are installed by default.

Comment: The weird thing is, all my variables is white, strings as well etc. The werid thing is that intellisense is still working.

Answer (score 0):

I am using VS 2017. Closing the IDE and then reopening Visual Studio solved my problem.