# Ms Visual Studio IDE issue: On save, create an additional unique file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, ide

Recently I am facing following issue on Visual Studio 2013.

Issue: whenever I save a file (in VS IDE environment) It saves but create another file. like ***"oavt2pgv.uml~"*** , "***4lcp2dg5.d0z~".*** every time I save, it creates a unique file.

I had scanned the system and it has no virus. I have reset my VS settings as well, but no luck; the issues is still there.

It is happening only in VS environment. If I open the file in Notepad and save it does not create an additional file.

can anybody help me to resolve this.

Thanks

Naren

Comment: do you open VS 2013 in Administrator mode and then try it..? also have you made sure you are running the latest updates in VS2013.?

Comment: I tried in administrator mode as well, still has the same issue. It was working fine it came all of sudden. may be some setting issues, not sure.

Comment: sounds like you may have a program running that you're not aware of or a `Virus` what happens if you create a file as `.txt` does the same thing happen.. ? have you tried shutting down and restarting..? try getting a more advanced virus-scan program and run it on your machine..

Comment: Any file update within the VS IDE creates additional file. I tried all the options like shutting down, restarting and did the virus scan as well but no luck.

Comment: Try devenv.exe /SafeMode http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182471/how-to-run-visual-studio-without-plugin-and-all-third-party-feature

Comment: I had tried both the option devenv.exe /SafeMode and devenv.exe/resetsetting; It did not resolve the issue :(

Comment: Re-installation of visual studio resolved my issue. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-installation of visual studio resolved my issue. Thank you all for your help