# Turning Off Autoselection of Entire Words in SQL Server Management Studio and Visual Studio 2010

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Is there any way to shut off autoselection of entire words in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) 2014 and Visual Studio 2010? I'm not sure what the formal name of this "feature" is (which makes it difficult to conduct a search for duplicate topics on StackOverflow, of which I've found none so far) but it's easy to describe: whenever I click on a query in SSMS, the editor automatically selects the entire word, instead of placing the caret at the mousepoint. The behavior isn't always consistent; sometimes SSMS and VS don't select the entire word, but I can't pin down the common denominators that trigger it. The same behavior occurs when writing code in Visual Studio, which I've included in this question because they're built on much the same codebase (as anyone who's ever delved into SSMS automation can attest) and share a lot of functionality in common, like similar menu systems, shortcuts, etc.

I find this behavior annoying and a drag on productivity, especially when I'm typing really rapidly; I know where I want my mouse to go better than the GUI does, LOL. If anyone can tell me how to shut it off so that mouse clicks no longer autoselect entire words in SSMS and Visual Studio 2010, it'd be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Sounds annoying, I've never encountered that "feature". As extensions can often be shared between those 2 apps, try running VS in [safe mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182471/how-to-run-visual-studio-without-plugin-and-all-third-party-feature), if the problem disappears a 3rd part extension is the cause.  If it persists try the reset option in the options -> keyboard page.

Comment: Thanks I may give that a shot - it never occurred to me that an add-in might be responsible. I'm going to amend my post to note that the behavior is inconsistent; I'm not sure what the triggers for it are.

Comment: Are you sure that it's not an issue with your mouse/mouse drivers. Is it actually registering a double click when you click once? I had that once on a mouse that was on it's way out. Try a different mouse to see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: I'll give that a shot too Rich, thanks. I use a Logitech gaming mouse for coding so I don't think it'd be an issue, but I'll test it out to be sure.

Comment: I haven't yet been able to verify any of these potential causes but will post back here when I do, in case someone else runs into the same problem. It's a constant problem so I have plenty of incentive to figure out a solution, but it may take some time to pin it down.