# c# build or pressing f5 seems like autopress the Delete key where ever my cursor pointed at

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

this is my code before i press the build or F5 button

```
        using (var context = new DeliveryDriverContext())
        {
            return (from a in context.STNKs //my cursor is here
                    where a.PlatNo == platNo
                    select a).FirstOrDefault();

        }
```

and when i Build the project or press the f5 button the code become like this

```
        using (var context = new DeliveryDriverContext())
        {
            return (from a in context.STNKswhere a.PlatNo == platNo
                    select a).FirstOrDefault();

        }
```

and of course it cause errors at that line,and its annoying. is there anyone know how make like it used to be,pressing f5 or build without changing anything

Comment: It's something new for me. Does it hurt to type space between STNKs and where?

Comment: thats not my question. my question is how to make it like it used to be. pressing f5 or build without changing anything.

Comment: Try starting visual studio in safe mode, to eliminate the possibility of a rogue plugin causing the issue.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182471/how-to-run-visual-studio-without-plugin-and-all-third-party-feature

Comment: try pressing ctrl+k+d to eliminate any white spaces