# Visual Studio 2010 crashes

Tags: visual-studio-2010, biztalk

Visual Studio 2010 stops working every time I am creating or adding a new project and crashes with "Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 has stopped working".

On details I get the following errors: "

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: devenv.exe
  Application Version:  10.0.40219.1
  Application Timestamp:    4d5f2a73
  Fault Module Name:    clr.dll
  Fault Module Version: 4.6.1087.0
  Fault Module Timestamp:   583e5b8e
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 000030d0
  OS Version:   6.3.9600.2.0.0.272.7
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 0e72
  Additional Information 2: 0e720e4bb45f9178e5a9d38daa53fc02
  Additional Information 3: f679
  Additional Information 4: f679a242f56e8d70edce702dbd5ef2ed
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running Visual Studio 2010 in safe mode.
To do this, please take a look at this post: [how to run visual studio without plugin and all third party feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182471/how-to-run-visual-studio-without-plugin-and-all-third-party-feature)