# Visual Studio 2017: Solution Explorer and other ancillary tabs/windows always closing and having to be re-opened

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Every time I close a solution, or start debugging, or stop debugging, everything except the main code tab auto-hides.

This includes anything docked to the right - like the Solution Explorer, Properties, etc. (for me at least).  It also includes everything docked to the bottom - like the Find Results, Output, Immediate Window, Error List, etc. (again, for me at least).

I cannot find a setting that keeps these docked items open. I find it very annoying that I have to keep re-opening them and would like to find a more permanent solution.

I recently updated from VS 2013. It did not do this.

Is there a setting? Is it something else? I am running on Windows Server 2012 R2. I open Visual Studios as the Administrator.

Comment: This is likely a Visual Studio 2017 bug. You should submit the bug using the built in tool for that.

Comment: That may be a 3rd party (extension, addin, etc.). You can try /SafeMode: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182471/how-to-run-visual-studio-without-plugin-and-all-third-party-feature

Comment: Also Check **Manage Visual Studio Performance** options. You may have set it to 'Do not show window at startup' for these tool windows.

Comment: @Sanket Thanks, that was it. I could not find that menu option; I kept looking for it under Tools/Options and never ventured over to Help. Add this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To Optimize Visual Studio Startup Time, VS2017 has introduced new feature **Manage Visual Studio Performance** under help menu. Using this option, one can override startup behavior of tool window like error list, package manager console etc.

[image: VS2017 Startup Time optimization]

For more information, refer [Optimize Visual Studio Startup Time](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt744573.aspx).

Comment: Switching from "Auto hide..." to "Do not show..." helped.