# Building c# MVC asp.net api webpage- I want to use the index.cshtml page but get the failure message: CS1980 (see text for code description)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have now build a webpage for some API stuff- I now want to use the index.cshtml file (which is build into the structure) - but when I open the index.cshtml file or the Layout.cshtml or the Error.cshtml file in the Visual Studio - I get the exception message as:

> CS1980 C# Cannot define a class or member that utilizes 'dynamic' because the compiler required type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.DynamicAttribute' cannot be found. Are you missing a reference?

For some time ago, the Azure was installed in my project by a mistake - but I uninstalled it (maybe that was the reason).

Comment: Try running Visual Studio without any extensions.  If that doesn't help, try repairing you visual studio installation.

Comment: Hi Neil. Thanks for you answer - how do I run the VS without extensions?

Comment: Try this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182471/how-to-run-visual-studio-without-plugin-and-all-third-party-feature

Comment: Hi Neil - thanks again. I run VS in safemode through the command line - and you are right - no error code - what do you think I have to do?

Comment: Disable all your extensions, and then re-enable them one by one until one of them stops it working.

Comment: Hi Neil. I have tried to disable all the extensions now. But with no success. I have also tried to compare it to an older project (looks like this project) which is working, and also with the same extensions - but no success. I hope you still are here...

Comment: http://billwg.blogspot.com/2008/12/useful-commands-for-solving-visual.html

Answer (score 0):

I have deleted the `View` folder (where the index file was included) and added the it again, like on [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yhhVicqyi1U) video.