# Visual Studio 2019 Extensions loading infinitely

Tags: visual-studio

I have ran in this issue, and it is weird. I have installed Visual Studio some time ago, and haven't launched it in like 2 months. Now when I create project it is really laggy, and cpu or ssd is not running at 100%.

Instead, it tries to load extensions, but it seems that it is failing. I have tried to repair it through Visual Studio Installer, and running VS as an admin, but that gave no result. The extension it tries to load is kind of random and can vary between the launches.

Problem screenshot - https://prnt.sc/war0b8

Comment: Try to start visual studio without all installed extensions :"You can either run devenv.exe /SafeMode using the command line or by creating a new shortcut. The devenv.exe executable is located in the \Common7\IDE\devenv.exe directory under the directory your visual studio is installed." https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182471/how-to-run-visual-studio-without-plugin-and-all-third-party-feature  - - the first answer from John

Comment: Thanks @user8606929 it helped sort of. But now 2 new problems appears. It is not lagging by trying to load some extensions, but now it will not load anything. Creating new projects gives - https://prnt.sc/war42p And trying to open existing one - https://prnt.sc/war4ht

Comment: Is the latest version of Visual Studio installed?
And which Visual Studio edition are you using?