# Project unloaded after git commit

Tags: git, visual-studio, github

So I have never experienced this issue before and hope that someone else has. I'm working on a application and make a few changes then commit and push to GitHub. Once I do this the project I made changes gets unloaded from Visual Studio. When I try to reload the project I get the following error.

[image]

If I clone a new copy of the repo locally I can make changes and use the solution as usual, but this happens again if I make a commit and push it to GitHub.

Any thoughts would help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the project I was working on would only open in VS 2019 and VS 2022 caused this issue. Not sure why, but it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Try first to launch Visual Studio [without extension (`/SafeMode`)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47806849/6309) and reload your project then.

That would check if the error is linked to an extension/plugin or not.

Comment: I'm not using VSCode, but would this still work in the standard Visual Studio IDE?

Comment: @NorSer Sorry for the mix-up. I have edited the answer to address Visual Studio, not VSCode.

Comment: I tried launching Visual Studio using the method you described. (See image below)
[Command](https://imgur.com/a/2ZMsZno)
Then when I opened the solution none of the projects loaded. (see image below)
[Projects](https://imgur.com/a/GlAUa5A)

Comment: @NorSer Can you try and [reload the solution/project](http://www.liangshunet.com/en/202007/934375421.htm)?

Comment: When I reload the project / solution I get the same error.

Comment: I get this error when I load the solution in SafeMode
`D:\Path\To\Project\project.csproj : error  : Project '{ProjectName}' could not be opened because the Visual C# 2022 language service could not be created. Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServer.Client, Version=17.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`

Comment: @NorSer OK, that could be because, in safe mode, no extension is loaded. Try and activate just that one extension