# VsCode started linting everythin randomly

Tags: visual-studio-code

Anybody has an idea why this is happening for C and CPP files. The code itself is fine, it was not linting anything yesterday, and now I open it and it looks like this.
It's probably an Intellisense config thing right ?

[image: example]

Comment: Have you installed any extensions recently? If so, you can try disabling them to see if it fixes your problem. You can also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182471/how-to-run-visual-studio-without-plugin-and-all-third-party-feature

Comment: Show what the problem description for the `#include "main.h"` problem is. Show also the problem information for your header file. Show the actual problem description text. If the main.h file also has problems with includes, track those problems down to the "lowest" include problem and show that.